# C# WinForms running only in administration user

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am Using `VS2008` to create `winforms`. Every programm I make seems to run only for administrator users.
If user isn't administrator programm fails to start.
I bet this is a release option in `Visual Studio` but haven't managed to find out.

```
        string r, w;
        List<string> tags = new List<string>();
        private ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip1;
        StreamWriter sr=new StreamWriter(@"C:\\System\\out.txt",true);        
        private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();           

        System.Threading.Timer ClipboardUnload;
        public Form1()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();                             
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            ClipboardUnload = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(ClipboardUnload_Tick), null, 0, Properties.Settings.Default.Persist);
        }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Need some more information, like what the programs do and what kind of calls they make etc?

Comment: There is no such release option. You may have copied something into your manifest file that makes the application require elevated rights, but you'd have to do that for every project individually. Also, you have not stated what you mean by "seems to run" - does it show an UAC prompt or does it simply to do what you want and produce exceptions due to missing rights?

Comment: Does the user you try to run under have access to the `C:\System` folder? And again: Does the program fail to write anything or does it show an UAC prompt?

Comment: UAC is disable. The program just fails..

Comment: Then what's the exception? And does the user have write-rights to `C:\System`? What's the code that actually throws the error?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That was it... simple user hasn't got priv to write on particullar folder..If you like post an answer and I will accept it, thanks by all means

Comment: @apomene You might want to accept David's answer - it basically says it all, only for the wrong folder :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the program is writing something in the C:\system directory the user running the program will require write-rights for that folder.

Comment: you might want to change your answer so it reflects the recent edits of the question and the comments to the question, as I suggested the OP to accept it.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Done. I was suspecting this was the case. We ran into this problem a lot with old software when we migrated from XP where everyone had admin rights.

Comment: This was, however, not quite the edit I meant :-) `C:\System` seems to be a folder made by the poster, so you can't assume one requires admin rights. You should write that the user account trying to write to `C:\System` will require respective write-rights.